# cant share google spreadsheet with gserviceaccount email id - gspread

Tags: google-sheets, gspread

i am following the following tutorial http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html and i am stuck at step 7 which states to share the spreadsheet with json['client_email'].

i tried doing that but i get an email stating that the domain of the json['client_email] was not resolved (DNS ERROR - failure notification).

i even opened an issue at github, but i got no replies https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/342 so i am trying here with the gspread tag

Comment: What kind of credentials did you create in the developer console? It didn't look right on the Github issue